# How much more voltage is required, theoretically, for a lightning bolt to strike than is actually observed/detected?

Tags: electricity, earth, lightning, weather, meteorology

Scientists are always saying that they cannot fully explain how lightning works, especially when it comes to the fact that there doesn't seem to be anywhere near enough potential difference between the cloud(s) and the ground to generate it.

How large is the difference between the voltage theoretically required for lightning to strike and that which is actually observed?

Comment: While it's apparently true that it's not exactly understood how a sufficient potential difference builds up between the ground and the clouds to generate a lightning, I'm not sure about the claim that there is any known discrepancy between the theoretically required voltage and that which was measured experimentally. I may be wrong of course, but can you please provide a citation for this second claim?